# Returning viewmodel from view gives an ampty object in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm working on a small project. The intention is to maintain the presences of a couple of users on some specific dates. This dates are first chosen by the user.

Therefor I use a view model. This will provide all possible data with a check box in a table to show to the user.

In the view itself I walk every day in the given view modeland I let the view generate a tag  and an editor object (Html.EditorFor ()). All this is surrounded by the form creation (@ Html.BeginForm ()). Rendering the view is not the problem.

The problem is when I try to return the view model. The viewmodel object that I receive is an object with null - objects in themselves. Like it has been created by the default constructor.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult OpldagenLt()
    {
        var lt = _gebruikerRepository.GeefTraject(_gebruikerRepository.TrajectId);
        List<DatumModel> data = new List<DatumModel>();
        foreach (Opleidingdag opldag in lt.GeefOpleidingdagenKleinerDanOfGelijkAanVandaag())
            data.Add(new DatumModel(opldag));

        List<ToekomstModel> toekomst = new List<ToekomstModel>();
        foreach (Opleidingdag opldag in lt.GeefOpleidingdagenGroterDanVandaag())
            toekomst.Add(new ToekomstModel(opldag));

        DataModel datamod = new DataModel();
        datamod.Datums = data;
        datamod.Toekomst = toekomst;

        if (lt.ControleerAantalOpleidingdagen())
        {
             _gebruikerRepository.GekozenDagen = GekozenDagen(datamod) as List<Opleidingdag>;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Aanwezigheid");
        }
        return View(datamod);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OpldagenLt(DataModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        _gebruikerRepository.GekozenDagen = GekozenDagen(model) as List<Opleidingdag>;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Aanwezigheid");
    }

    public ICollection<Opleidingdag> GekozenDagen(DataModel datamod)
    {
        List<Opleidingdag> dagen = new List<Opleidingdag>();
            foreach (DatumModel datum in datamod.Datums)
            {
                dagen.Add(datum.Dag);
            }
        return dagen;
    }
```

View:

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm( "OpldagenLt", "Leertraject", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">reeds begonnen dagen</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in @Model.Datums)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag.Dag.Day)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag.Dag.Month)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag.Dag.Year)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Checked)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<div id="toekomst">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Dagen in de toekomst</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in @Model.Toekomst)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag.Dag.Day)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag.Dag.Month)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag.Dag.Year)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Volgende"/></p>
</div>
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ProjectII.Models.domain;

namespace ProjectII.Viewmodels
{
public class DataModel
{
    public  DataModel()
    {
        Datums = new List<DatumModel>();
    }

    public ICollection<DatumModel> Datums { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ToekomstModel> Toekomst{ get; set; }
}

public class DatumModel
{
    public DatumModel()
    {
        Dag = new Opleidingdag(new DateTime().Date);
        Checked = true;
    }
    public DatumModel(Opleidingdag opldag)
    {
        Dag = opldag;
        Checked = true;
    }

    public Opleidingdag Dag { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class ToekomstModel
{
    public ToekomstModel()
    {
        Dag = new Opleidingdag(new DateTime().Date);
    }
    public ToekomstModel(Opleidingdag opldag)
    {
        Dag = opldag;
    }

    public Opleidingdag Dag { get; set; }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Do you have your `@model` declared in the view?

Comment: you mean this? @model ProjectII.Viewmodels.DataModel

Comment: You receive an object containing null objects. You mean the `ProjectII.Viewmodels.DataModel` is not null, but the `Datums` and `Toekomst` properties are null? Or are the items in the `List<ToekomstModel>` and the `List<DatumModel>` null? When debugging, are the 'data' and `toekomst` objects properly filled when you assign them to the properties of `datamod`?

Comment: First
The properties are null when recieving the parameter in the HttpPost method.
What do you mean with assigning them to the properties of datamod? in the getMethod? or?

Comment: Ah.. That your issue was with post wasn't obvious from your question (you spoke of returning the viewmodel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stephen: thanks for the help.
with keeping your answer in my mind I finally succeeded returning those data.

I changed the foreach into a for
and changed ICollection to a List

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ProjectII.Models.domain;


namespace ProjectII.Viewmodels
{
public class DataModel
{
    public List<DatumModel> Datums { get; set; }
    public List<ToekomstModel> Toekomst{ get; set; }
}

public class DatumModel
{
    public DatumModel()
    {
        Dag = new Opleidingdag(new DateTime().Date);
        Checked = true;
    }
    public DatumModel(Opleidingdag opldag)
    {
        Dag = opldag;
        Checked = true;
    }

    public Opleidingdag Dag { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class ToekomstModel
{
    public ToekomstModel()
    {
        Dag = new Opleidingdag(new DateTime().Date);
    }
    public ToekomstModel(Opleidingdag opldag)
    {
        Dag = opldag;
    }

    public Opleidingdag Dag { get; set; }
}
}
```

view:

```
@model ProjectII.Viewmodels.DataModel

@using(@Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">reeds begonnen dagen</th>
        </tr>

         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Datums.Count; i++)
       {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Datums[i].Dag.Dag.Day)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Datums[i].Dag.Dag.Month)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Datums[i].Dag.Dag.Year)</td>
                <td>
                     @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Datums[i].Checked)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    @*@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Datums.Count; i++)
    {
        <div> @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Datums[i].Dag.Dag) 
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Datums[i].Checked) </div>
    }*@

</div> 
<div id="toekomst">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Dagen in de toekomst</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in @Model.Toekomst)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag.Dag.Day)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag.Dag.Month)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dag.Dag.Year)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Volgende"/></p>
</div>
}
```

Now I recieve a model with the right values

thanks for the help people

Answer (score 0):

With the way you construct your view, the ModelBinder cannot differantiate between the different elements in the list, and doesn't recognize them as items in the list. Try constructing the view like this:

```
@{ int datumteller = 0; }
 @foreach (var item in @Model.Datums)
 {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @Model.Datums[datumteller].Dag.Dag.Day)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @Model.Datums[datumteller].Dag.Dag.Month)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @Model.Datums[datumteller].Dag.Dag.Year)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => @Model.Datums[datumteller].Checked)</td>
        </tr>
 datumteller++;
 }

@{ int toekomstteller = 0; }
 @foreach (var item in @Model.Toekomst)
 {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @Model.Toekomst[toekomstteller].Dag.Dag.Day)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @Model.Toekomst[toekomstteller].Dag.Dag.Month)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @Model.Toekomst[toekomstteller].Dag.Dag.Year)</td>
        </tr>
  toekomstteller++
  }
```

Comment: so you mean just adding to the view like this, or do i have to add extra code somewhere else too?

Comment: just add those instead of your foreach loops

Comment: so how am I supposed to reach each object?